# Bash: Iteratively Mount First Drive, Volume Or Partition Matching A Naming Scheme, Ignoring Second and Subsequent Matches

Tags: bash, loops, testing, conditional-statements, matching

I want to:

1. iterate over a list;
2. find the first instance in which there is a matching substring;
3. do something about that;
4. ignore any subsequent matches.
5. continue to the end of the list.

More concretely:

```
#! /bin/bash

target_ORG=$(ls /usr/local/etc/ini/system/ORG)
target_DOMAIN=$(ls /usr/local/etc/ini/system/DOMAIN)
target_SITE=$(ls /usr/local/etc/ini/system/SITE)
target_DEVICE=$(ls /usr/local/etc/ini/system/DEVICE)
target_VOLUME=$(ls /usr/local/etc/ini/system/VOLUME)
target_HOST=$(ls /usr/local/etc/ini/system/HOST)


instanceList=$(ls /dev/disk/by-partlabel)

for i in $instanceList 
 
  do
    instance_ORG=${i:0:3}
    instance_DOMAIN=${i:4:3}
    instance_SAN=${i:8:1}
    instance_SITE=${i:10:1}
    instance_DEVICE=${i:12:5}
    instance_VOLUME=${i:18:6}
    
    <PSEUDOCODE>
   
    Compare the instance_* strings with the target_* strings
    IF they all match
       THEN
           mount $i /path/to/mountpoint

    </PSEUDOCODE>

  done
```

Where:

1. the specific devices available vary across time
2. the *partlabel* format is: xxx-xxx-x-x-xxxxx-xxxxxx (e.g. 001-001-1-1-00001-000001), indicating a disk partition as being ORG-DOMAIN-SAN-SITE-DEVICE-VOLUME
3. the */usr/local/etc/ini/system/** directories each contain a file named for the corresponding substring - allowing changes to be made by simply renaming (rather than having to manipulate the content of) files
4. /path/to/mountpoint is the mountpoint for the matching $instance_SAN

```
That is ... 

xxx-xxx-1-x-xxxxx-xxxxxx mounts to /path/to/1
xxx-xxx-2-x-xxxxx-xxxxxx mounts to /path/to/2
xxx-xxx-3-x-xxxxx-xxxxxx mounts to /path/to/3
```

The problem with the *for* loop is that it will simply assign the next value to the *$instance_** variable, when I want it to keep the first found instance - so, xxx-xxx-1-1-xxxxx-xxxxxx will be overmounted with xxx-xxx-1-2-xxxxx-xxxxxx and so on.

A *case* test will find and keep the first found instance, but won't then iterate over the rest of *$instanceList*

```
e.g. given

/usr/local/etc/ini/system/ORG/001
/usr/local/etc/ini/system/DOMAIN/001
/usr/local/etc/ini/system/SITE/1
/usr/local/etc/ini/system/DEVICE/00001
/usr/local/etc/ini/system/VOLUME/000001
/usr/local/etc/ini/system/HOST/000001

...and...

*$instanceList* of:

001-001-1-1-00001-000001
001-001-1-1-00001-000002
001-001-1-2-00001-000001
001-001-1-2-00001-000002
001-001-2-2-00001-000001
001-001-2-2-00002-000001
001-001-3-5-00001-000002

001-001-1-1-00001-000001 will get mounted to /path/to/1
and everything else will be ignored.
```

I need to mount the first matching device and ignore any others with a matching $instance_SAN, whilst continuing to iterate across $instanceList.

```
e.g. given the above 

001-001-1-1-00001-000001 should be mounted to /path/to/1
001-001-1-1-00001-000002 should be ignored
001-001-1-2-00001-000001 should be ignored
001-001-1-2-00001-000002 should be ignored
001-001-2-2-00001-000001 should be mounted to /path/to/2
001-001-2-2-00002-000001 should be ignored
001-001-3-5-00001-000002 should be mounted to /path/to/3
```

Nested *if* tests are too brittle.


Multiple *case* tests *could* work

```
<PSEUDOCODE>
 
Case of $instance_SAN=1: mount device/partion to /path/to/$instance_SAN
Case of $instance_SAN=2: mount device/partion to /path/to/$instance_SAN
Case of $instance_SAN=3: mount device/partion to /path/to/$instance_SAN

</PSEUDOCODE>
```

But I just can't wrap my head around how to iterate across $instanceList without simply breaking after the first match.

I realise this is probably very basic, but my bash just isn't very advanced, I'm afraid.

I'd like to avoid solutions such as *autoFS*, however, so that the approach isn't reliant upon anything more than a core Linux install; even something like a minimal Arch/Gentoo, or even LFS, should be able to provision everything without the need for any extra utilities - also, this has to be done pre-login, so, I don't think a 'third party' solution would work anyway.


=======

UPDATE

=======


Following the suggestion, by pjh, to try `mountpoint || mount` ...

```
#! /bin/bash

target_ORG=$(ls '/usr/local/etc/ini/system/ORG')
target_DOMAIN=$(ls 'usr/local/etc/ini/system/DOMAIN')
target_SITE=$(ls '/usr/local/etc/ini/system/SITE')
target_DEVICE=$(ls '/usr/local/etc/ini/system/DEVICE')
target_VOLUME=$(ls '/usr/local/etc/ini/system/VOLUME')
target_HOST=$(ls '/usr/local/etc/ini/system/HOST')


echo "target_ORG=$target_ORG"
echo "target_DOMAIN=$target_DOMAIN"
echo "target_SITE=$target_SITE"
echo "target_DEVICE=$target_DEVICE"
echo "target_VOLUME=$target_VOLUME"
echo "target_HOST=$target_HOST"


instanceList=$(ls /dev/disk/by-partlabel)


for i in {1..3}

    do

      for n in $instanceList 

        do

          echo -e '\n'
          echo "i = $i"
          echo "n = $n"

          instance_ORG=${n:0:3}
          instance_DOMAIN=${n:4:3}
          instance_SAN=${n:8:1}
          instance_SITE=${n:10:1}
          instance_DEVICE=${n:12:5}
          instance_VOLUME=${n:18:6}

          mountpoint "/mnt/test/$i" || mount "$n" "/mnt/test/$i"

      done
done
```

... results in

```
target_ORG=000
target_DOMAIN=000
target_SITE=1
target_DEVICE=00000
target_VOLUME=000001
target_HOST=000001


i = 1
n = 000-000-1-1-00000-000001
/mnt/test/1 is not a mountpoint
mount: /mnt/test/1: special device 000-000-1-1-00000-000001 does not exist.

i = 1
n = 000-000-2-1-00000-000001
/mnt/test/1 is not a mountpoint
mount: /mnt/test/1: special device 000-000-2-1-00000-000001 does not exist.

i = 1
n = 000-000-3-1-00000-000001
/mnt/test/1 is not a mountpoint
mount: /mnt/test/1: special device 000-000-3-1-00000-000001 does not exist.


i = 2
n = 000-000-1-1-00000-000001
/mnt/test/2 is not a mountpoint
mount: /mnt/test/2: special device 000-000-1-1-00000-000001 does not exist.

i = 2
n = 000-000-2-1-00000-000001
/mnt/test/2 is not a mountpoint
mount: /mnt/test/2: special device 000-000-2-1-00000-000001 does not exist.

i = 2
n = 000-000-3-1-00000-000001
/mnt/test/2 is not a mountpoint
mount: /mnt/test/2: special device 000-000-3-1-00000-000001 does not exist.


i = 3
n = 000-000-1-1-00000-000001
/mnt/test/3 is not a mountpoint
mount: /mnt/test/3: special device 000-000-1-1-00000-000001 does not exist.

i = 3
n = 000-000-2-1-00000-000001
/mnt/test/3 is not a mountpoint
mount: /mnt/test/3: special device 000-000-2-1-00000-000001 does not exist.

i = 3
n = 000-000-3-1-00000-000001
/mnt/test/3 is not a mountpoint
mount: /mnt/test/3: special device 000-000-3-1-00000-000001 does not exist.
```

But they very much do exist - which is proven by simply manually mounting them to the same locations (so, it doesn't appear to be a problem of the kernel not being aware of them).

And `ls -l /dev/disk/by-partlabel` lists a `b` the first column - so it doesn't seem to be that they aren't recognised as block devices either.

Am I running into [the issue](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) referred to by Cyrus? (I can't find anything *else* that seems to hint at the cause).



FWIW ...

DMESG reports some errors

```
[ 7064.170224] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.0
[ 7064.170242] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[ 7064.170247] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:a115] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[ 7064.170254] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
...
[11372.230786] 000-000-1-1-00000-000001: Can't open blockdev
[11372.232977] 000-000-2-1-00000-000001: Can't open blockdev
[11372.235242] 000-000-3-1-00000-000001: Can't open blockdev
```

After the final `done`, I tried adding

```
export "$n"
```

The result was

```
export: '000-000-3-1-00000-000001': not a valid identifier
```

Changing the PARTLABEL to remove the '-' symbols resulted in

```
export: '0000003100000000001: not a valid identifier
```

So, unless my export is incorrect, it's not those either.

Changed it to

```
export N="$n"

and

export "N=$n"
```

There was no error this time, but echoing $N returned a null output.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Probably something like this: `mkdir "$mountpoint" && mount "$i" "$mountpoint"`. So, if the mount point exists before calling `mount` then it won't mount. All possible mount points must be removed by `rmdir` before running the script.

Comment: @Cyrus, Re: Why not parse ls

Useful to know, thanks - I hadn't considered that but, of course, nefarious intent aside, there's always the possibility of an unhappy accident.

@ M. Nejat Atfin

Won't work, as I can't anticipate which devices will be available and can't create folders in advance. Moreover, there are only three legitimate mountpoints, and they're predetermined.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and then format ALL your input and output text blocks and any other snippets of code as Code Blocks, just like the script and the final text block in your question.

Comment: I'm really not sure I follow.

As you note, I formatted the (pseudo)code blocks.

There *are* no others. And no input/output text as such (although I think I might know what you mean). But there's no indication in that guide on *what* formatting to use for them, just how to use markdown formatting, when you *know* what (you want) to use. So, I'm at something of a loss: they aren't code, so I'm guessing a code block is inappropriate. What *should* I use?

Comment: I hope that's what you meant.

Comment: Given what you have written, I can see why '001-001-1-1-00001-000001' should be mounted.  However, I can't see why `001-001-2-2-00001-000001` and `001-001-3-5-00001-000002` should be mounted.  The SITE fields (2 and 5) don't match the target SITE field (1).  Do you need only some subset of the target fields to match?

Comment: There is a Linux command called `mountpoint` that detects if a path has something mounted on it.  If your requirement is to avoid "overmounts" then you should be able to do it with `mountpoint -q "$mountpoint" || mount "$i" "$mountpoint"`.

Comment: @pjh: There is a large number of devices that could be connected at any boottime (too many to list individually in a script/conf file) - each with a unique PARTLABEL. There is no guarantee that the same ones will be available each time. The need is, therefore, for the first device with a matching $instance_SAN to the appropriate mountpoint and all others with the same $instance_SAN value to be ignored - allowing failover such that ...-x-1-... will be mounted if detected, ...-x-2-... if detected when ...-x-1-... is not available, ...-x-3-..., if neither of the others are present, etc.

Comment: @pjh: The SITE field is for the purpose of limiting the process to devices located at a specific site rather than simply the first one available, if that is a requirement. So, it's not a consideration at this stage in the proceedings, which is about simply provisioning the first available device matching the SAN field irrespective of which one it is or how many others there are. Limiting the search will be done by examining $target_SITE and, if it's >0, ignoring any device that doesn't match both SAN *and* SITE.

Comment: The ultimate failover is a local partition on the system drive, that mirrors the FS structure and has a synchronised subset of the data available on the others: if no devices are detected, instead of the device with the corresponding $instance_SAN being mounted, it defaults to the local directory on the local partition - that way, there's graceful degradation (there is always *something* available to work with).

Comment: I'll investigate your ```mountpoint -q "$mountpoint" || mount "$i" "$mountpoint"``` suggestion - thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLUTION]

```
#! /bin/bash

target_ORG=$(ls '/usr/local/etc/ini/system/ORG')
target_DOMAIN=$(ls '/usr/local/etc/ini/system/DOMAIN')
target_SITE=$(ls '/usr/local/etc/ini/system/SITE')
target_DEVICE=$(ls '/usr/local/etc/ini/system/DEVICE')
target_VOLUME=$(ls '/usr/local/etc/ini/system/VOLUME')
target_HOST=$(ls '/usr/local/etc/ini/system/HOST')


instanceList=$(ls '/dev/disk/by-partlabel')


for i in {1..3} ; do

      for n in $instanceList ; do

          instance_ORG=${n:0:3}
          instance_DOMAIN=${n:4:3}
          instance_SAN=${n:8:1}
          instance_SITE=${n:10:1}
          instance_DEVICE=${n:12:5}
          instance_VOLUME=${n:18:6}

          mountpoint -q /path/to/$i || mount /dev/disk/by-partlabel/$instance_ORG\-$instance_DOMAIN\-$i\-$instance_SITE\-$instance_DEVICE\-$instance_VOLUME /path/to/$i >/dev/null 2>&1

      done
done
```

To specify a specific subset from the available devices, substitute `$target_*` for `$instance_*` in the `mount` command

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the requirements is:

- The system has entries for devices under '/dev/disk/by-partlabel'.
- Each device is associated with a SAN.
- For each unique SAN, mount one (and only one) of the devices associated with it.

There are several ways to do that.  One ([Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)
-clean) possibility is:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

for san in 1 2 3 ; do
    for devpath in /dev/disk/by-partlabel/*-*-"$san"-*-*-*; do
        mount "$devpath" "/path/to/$san"
        break
    done
done
```

- The unconditional [break](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-break) means that the `for devpath in ...` loop will stop after mounting one device associated with the current value of `$san`.  The overall effect is to get one device mounted for each SAN.

Another (also [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)
-clean) way to do it is:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

is_mounted_san=()
for devpath in /dev/disk/by-partlabel/*-*-*-*-*-*; do
    IFS=- read -r _ _ san _ _ _ <<<"${devpath##*/}"
    (( ${is_mounted_san[san]-0} )) && continue
    mount "$devpath" "/path/to/$san"
    is_mounted_san[san]=1
done
```

- This uses the `is_mounted_san` array to keep track of which SANs have had an associated device mounted.
- See [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for an explanation of `IFS=- read -r _ _ san ...`.
- See the [Here Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) section in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) for an explanation of `... <<<...`.
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${devpath##*/}`.  (It removes everything up to and including the last `/` character in `$devpath`.)

Comment: Many thanks for that!

I've got it working in a quick and dirty way for now (see my own answer above), which is really all I needed at this stage - the subsequent steps in the project are the most significant ones and I need to get them resolved ASAP.

But, as noted by Cyrus, parsing ls is unsecure, so I'll come back to this afterwards and give your new suggestion(s) a try.